# How is VPS uptime almost 100%

Tags: unexpected-shutdown

I have been using DO and AWS for months and I have seen there was no downtime, at least I havent noticed and they do not notify me either.
But for the last 3 months at my company, we used softlayer and we have received not less than 3 emails about downtime that required a server reboot.

How do DO or AWS keeps the uptime almost 100%? Or are they really archieving that uptime?

Comment: Contact the Softlayer support team, uptime is something that varies with each company. There are no rules for this.

Comment: Easy... they can migrate you to different machines so you never experience downtime. Every company has their own setups.

Comment: `How do DO or AWS keeps the uptime almost 100%?` - Large sums of money spent on building a highly available, highly resilient and highly redundant infrastructure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do DO or AWS keeps the uptime almost 100%?

By using standard functionality in any enterprise level virtualization software. They migrate your VPS to another host before restarting the host. No downtime for the VPS.

The only downtime you would experience is a restart if the host fails hard (blows out power or something like that, without time for migration).

SoftLayer likely chooses a cheaper setup. And you choose softlayer likely because of the cheaper price.

Comment: yeah they charged damn high though. Anyway, could you be more specific on how migration is done? I dont believe the migration is completely transparent to me. For e.g. If I have a client connecting to my db server, would migration of the db server cut my connection?

Comment: It is. Open connnections move. There is downtime, but it is so small it is invisible for applications not specifically looking for it. Hyper-V, VmWare have documentation you can read. And yes, pricing for large providers is expensive.